# Kaa project with MQTT/CoAP - Release 1.0.0 banana beach

Tags: kaa

I'm planning to connect some sensor hardware with an IoT service platform. The sensors are connected to the interet with Thread/802.15.4 via a border router (gateway). So, each sensor has a IPv6 address. I would like to connect them to a  [kaa project enviroment](https://www.kaaproject.org/).

It seems that kaa project supports neither MQTT nor CoAP out-of-the-box. But I found for instance [this pull request about CoAP](https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa/pull/1361) .

What is the current state? Do I need to implement a CoAP or MQTT layer myself?

I also read that the kaa release 1.0.0 banana beach will support MQTT out-of-the-box. Is there already a release date? And will CoAP be supported as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting into Kaa myself, but I see MQTT is one of the default transports.

See- https://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Transports

I also ran across this project on GH-
https://github.com/ethicstechOSS/MQTT-with-Kaa-server